# Server name along with folder structure php

Tags: php

I have a little task on hand now. I want to send an email to a newly registered user from a page along with a link to confirm the email address.

In the email code, i have used `$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]` to generate the link.
This works fine if the application is in the root of the domain. For example:

`www.example.com/file.php`

But I have an extra folder i.e `www.example.com/folder_name/file.php`

Is there any way to generate the link www.example.com/folder_name/file.php without hardcoding the name of the folder?

Comment: Do you want `www.example.com/folder_1/folder_2/file.php` to have links to `www.example.com/folder_1/file_2.php` or `www.example.com/folder_1/folder_2/file_2.php`?

Comment: I want the link as [ www.example.com/folder_1/folder_2/file_2.php ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link to another script within the same folder you should be able to do something like this:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/myscript.php';
```

Comment: That would work if i want to generate a link to the current working file, but I want a link to another file from the same folder.

Comment: Sorry @anshu Looks like I got the complete wrong end of the stick. I have updated my answer with what I think you're after.

Comment: Exactly ! I think this should solve the problem. Thanks mate :)